# Why does my url reference in my test controller don't pass succesfully trought the if(isset)

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I have a problem with my testRapportParams function in my ProduitsControllerTest. When I enter the url with a variable, it passes trought the controller passing by the else part, which it means the variable is not set. The thing is ,in the core program, the ProduitsController works perfectly well. I don't understand it doesn't work in my tests.

Here the code of my test controller:

```
//in my ProduitsControllerTest
public function testRapportParams()
{
    //Test if the year in the url can be found  
    $dateCompare = array(Date('Y'), Date('Y')-1, Date('Y')-2, Date('Y')-3,Date('Y')-4,Date('Y')-5,Date('Y')-6,Date('Y')-7);
    $produits = TableRegistry::get('Produits');

    //The url called by this is : '/produits/rapport?datecompare=2015'
    $this->get('/produits/rapport?datecompare='.$datecompare[1]);
    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $produitsnouveau = $this->viewVariable('produitsnouveau');
    $produitssupp = $this->viewVariable('produitssupp');

    //$produits->find('all')->where(['YEAR(__creation_ts) = ' => $datecompare[1]])
    //                      ->where('supp_le_ts is NULL')
    //                      ->count() == 0

    //$produits->find('all')->where(['YEAR(supp_le_ts) = ' => $datecompare[1]])
    //                      ->count() == 2

    //count($produitsnouveau) == 0 (supposed to be 0)
    //count($produitssupp) == 1 (supposed to be 2)

    $this->assertEquals($produits->find('all')->where(['YEAR(__creation_ts) = ' => $datecompare[1]])->where('supp_le_ts is NULL')->count(),count($produitsnouveau));
    $this->assertEquals($produits->find('all')->where(['YEAR(supp_le_ts) = ' => $datecompare[1]])->count(),count($produitssupp));

}
```

Here is the function I use for the test :

```
 public function rapport()
 {
   $datecompare = array(Date('Y'), Date('Y')-1, Date('Y')-2, Date('Y')-3,Date('Y')-4,Date('Y')-5,Date('Y')-6,Date('Y')-7);
   $this->set('datecompare',$datecompare);

   //The url called is : '/produits/rapport?datecompare=2015'
   if(isset($_GET['datecompare']))
   {
       $this->paginate = [
           'conditions' => [
               'Produits.supp_le_ts IS NULL',
               'YEAR(Produits.__creation_ts) = ' => $_GET['datecompare'],
           ],
           'contain' => ['Items'],
           'order' => ['nom' => 'asc']
       ];
       $produitsnouveau = $this->paginate($this->Produits); 

       $this->paginate = [
           'conditions' => [
               'YEAR(Produits.supp_le_ts) = ' => $_GET['datecompare'],
         ],
         'contain' => ['Items'],
         'order' => ['nom' => 'asc']
       ];
       $produitssupp = $this->paginate($this->Produits);
       debug($produitssupp);
       die;
   }else{
     $this->paginate = [
         'conditions' => [
             'Produits.supp_le_ts IS NULL',
             'YEAR(Produits.__creation_ts) = ' => $datecompare[0],
         ],
         'contain' => ['Items'],
         'order' => ['nom' => 'asc']
     ];
     $produitsnouveau = $this->paginate($this->Produits);

     $this->paginate = [
         'conditions' => [
             'YEAR(Produits.supp_le_ts) = ' => $datecompare[0],
         ],
         'contain' => ['Items'],
         'order' => ['nom' => 'asc']
     ];
     $produitssupp = $this->paginate($this->Produits);
   }

     $this->set('produitsnouveau',$produitsnouveau);
     $this->set('produitssupp',$produitssupp);
     $this->set('_serialize', ['produits']);
 }
```

I would like to understand why it always pass in the else part when used in my test but it work well when im using my browser in the main app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does so because you are not using the proper CakePHP techniques for retrieving request data, that is, the `\Cake\Network\Request` object, specifically `Request::query()`, like

```
$datecompare = $this->request->query('datecompare');
if ($datecompare !== null) {
    // ...
```

The integration test case just simulates requests, it doesn't dispatch real ones, and thus, `$_GET` will not be populated as it would pollute the global state, instead the data will be set directly to the request object.

See

- **[Source > \Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase::_buildRequest()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.3/src/TestSuite/IntegrationTestCase.php#L428)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Request > Query String Parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#query-string-parameters)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solve my problem. I was wondering, why do we have to do an unset after a isset as shown in the first link you post?

Comment: "_you_" don't have to do that, in case this is what you actually wanted to ask. The unset in that specific routine is probably being done because headers are defined in HTTP spec format (like `Content-Type`), and the request class expects them in PHP format (ie `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE`), so they shouldn't be passed to the request object config as they are unused and incompatible. @Ilappy666